# Can BitLocker be used with Windows CE 6?

Tags: windows-ce

A client has asked if we can amend their application which runs on Windows CE 6 to write to a BitlockerToGo USB stick so the data is encrypted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows CE doesn't support BitLocker (or BitLocker doesn't have a Windows CE version is maybe more correct).

Comment: Thanks @ctacke I love it when there is a simple answer :-)